# Convert instance object into JS object in "view" in order to assign into data- html attribute cuts off in middle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looping instance variable "@packages" set in controller and am trying to assign single object into one of the html element by using "data-". For changing ruby object into json i am using ".to_json" as follows:

```
<% @packages.each do |package| %>
    <% json_package=package.to_json %>
     <a href="#" data-single-package=<%= json_package %>></a>
<% end %>
```

However, on inspecting the anchor tag i found json object is cutting off in one of the property which had a value with space in between it.

[image]

As you can see, "title" property has value "annarpurna circuit", but ".to_json" is cutting off in space by adding ".

How can i make this whole string pass through??

Comment: @maxpleaner how is that related to the question here?

Comment: no, i don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to escape the value that you put into the html so that it won't break the html-attribute quoting.

if you want rails to handle quoting for you, you can use the `data` attribute that can be passed to tag-helpers like `link_to`.

ie:

```
<%= link_to "", "#", data: {"single-package" => package} %>
```

Comment: can you give an example of how to use `gsub` for this?

Comment: @maxpleaner how does `gsub` have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

The result of applying .to_json will convert object into string, and as string is cutting off due to not escaping space gsub does help to substiture space character with nbsp.

Here is how it solved it for me:

```
<% json_package.to_json.gsub(/\s/,"&nbsp;") %>
```